# Payment method for Swedish local bank

Tags: php, mysql, payment

I have a very simple PHP & MySQL website. I want to include a payment system in my website, but there only local bank payments in Sweden.

Is there any built-in module? Any idea how much that costs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in to PHP.

The first result for my Google search comes up with: [api.payson.se](http://api.payson.se)

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate with a payment service provider.  It's slightly more awkward since you're in Sweden, but a few popular options are:

- [Amazon Payments](https://payments.amazon.com/sdui/sdui/business?sn=devfps/o)
- [Google Checkout](https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/)
- [PayPal](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal) (Heavily out of favor, lots of frozen account problems)
- [Stripe](https://stripe.com/) (US only)